# How do I go about getting a free standing range replaced with a cooktop gas stove?

Tags: range, countertops, cooktops

This is in the US and the question is similar to [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/262495/is-it-easy-to-replace-range-gas-stove-with-cooktop-gas-stove). While the other question is whether something is "easy or not" I'm wondering about the feasibility specifically around changing countertops. One of the answers says a countertop change won't be necessary but I wonder about the difference in the countertop continuity - square/rectangle shaped hole vs gap in countertop to allow for the gas range. I would like to avoid changing my entire countertop or finding an exact match at this point. The countertop is Corian

Being able to do that will allow me to add cabinets below the cooktop and find other places instead to put the oven (perhaps an on the wall one etc). This part is not important though.

Thoughts?

Additional Info: this is home I've purchased recently and don't have too many details plus restricted access for a couple weeks.

Edit: Adding a picture. I know it looks good and everything but it came "as-is" with some issues and we want to replace it. It is 30" wide

[image: current gas range]

Comment: Depends on the material, age and condition of the existing countertop.  It may be impossible (eg a hard to match stone counter) or may be easy (eg a very low-end countertop that can be resurfaced, epoxied, etc) or maybe you can work the seams and differences into the design .. a photo would help.

Comment: Your question is quite nebulous. We're not a discussion forum. Please revise to ask something clear and specific about your case.

Comment: Its a house you just bought?   Common practice is to live in it for 6 months before committing to any major projects.  You may decide there are other things which are higher priority than swapping out a working stove for a range.

Comment: What material is your existing countertop, and what color?  Got pics?

Comment: Added a picture. Current countertop is Corian. I have a few other priorities yes but I budgeted for all of that going in and kitchen is kinda on the top 3 priority items

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care if (or deliberately don't try to, as a design element) the countertop around the cooktop matches the other countertops, this is easy enough - get a cabinet of the proper size, a section of countertop with an appropriate hole in it, deal with the gas plumbing access in the lower part of the cabinet, done.

This sink-related answer covers some options for dealing with countertop-non-matching, or matching, but for a specific material that's normally easy to get matching. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/163853/18078

If you wanted it to match, you have to find matching countertop material and depending on countertop material possibly someone with adequate skill at, and correct materials for, joining that countertop material. But since you claim not to care, no problem.

*Depending very much on fiddly details of the top-size and undermount space requirements of a specific replacement cooktop. you might find one that would overlay the hole while still fitting in it, and then you'd only need a "trim strip" of countertop material on the front, and some sort of support (like angle iron screwed to the wall) on the back. But that makes shopping for the cooktop more difficult than buying a like-size unit to the range.*

Answer (score 2):

Start by deciding what type/color cooktop you want. Pick a size that's the size of the range your replacing or smaller. Then start hunting for a cabinet that will fit in the space where the range used to be, the tighter the fit, the better. It might be easier to get one custom made. Get the top to match the cooktop, ie., most cooktops I've seen are black in finish so get a black countertop/cabinet top. Once the cabinet is leveled and secured, cut the hole for the cooktop you've got.

Comment: Most ranges (in the USA) are 24, 30, or 36 inches wide, and standard base cabinets in all those sizes are also common, so probably no need for custom-sizing unless the range is weird.

Comment: Most *induction* cooktops are black. But most *gas* cooktops are stainless steel.

Comment: Now, now folks. Stainless/Black? - Boooring. Head on down to the Habitat ReStore and get you some Avocado Green, Harvest Gold, Poppy Red or Burnt Orange appliances. Pick up a sink to match while you're at it. Live a little!

Comment: @Ecnerwal  We had a townhouse at Country Cub of Miami totally in Avocado Green.

Comment: "Cut the hole" OP will need to get a new countertop to cut a hole, because the existing counter is probably two separate pieces—ranges typically don't have any countertop in front or in back.

Comment: @Huesmann The new cabinet  would have it's own  counter top since the OP doesn't want a new one. That's where the hole gets cut.